# Plugin Un-install missing

Tags: moodle

Moodle plugins come up with install & uninstall option when $plugin variable is specified in version.php.

I couldn't see uninstall option for my customized authentication plugin:

```
$plugin->version   = 2015051100;        
$plugin->requires  = 2015050500;       
$plugin->component = 'auth_hotspot';
```

Once installation is done, When I run the plugin, Un-install option is missing. I even don't have an option to delete as it shows "missing from disk". (Moodle version: 2.9).

Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moodle does not allow to uninstall the auth plugin if any user-created using that plugin.

You need to delete the user from Database or convert the user's authentication method to manual or others.

https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=272751

Comment: Hello Prasanna, if I delete the users, even then I couldn't see uninstall option. Is there  additional way to uninstall the plugin.

Comment: Sry, I missed that, moodle does not delete the users from DB when you delete the user from moodle users list, You need to manually delete the user from DB. Convert the user's auth method is the best way for this issue.